# How to fit and wrap text inside SVG polygon

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I simply want to know how to generate an SVG path that centers, fits, and curves inside of a SVG polygon. I assume the method of doing this would be through Javascript. **Reference below.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described by Noah Veltman in this [post](https://bl.ocks.org/veltman/403f95aee728d4a043b142c52c113f82), the basic process is:

1. Turn the shape into a polygon of evenly-spaced points.
2. Generate a Voronoi diagram of those points.
3. Clip the edges.
4. Turn the edges into a graph.
5. Find the "longest shortest path" between any pair of perimeter nodes.
6. Smooth/simplify that path a bit.
7. Place text along the smoothed centerline with a .

See also this [source](https://eox.at/2015/12/curved-labels/).